# Not able to enter text in the text area using Selenium Web Driver C#

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

Following is the origin code.

I want to enter text in the following text box area. Not able to enter the data. Let me know, how can I enter text in the below text box.

```
    <td id="ctl00_cRight_ucSMS_redSMSBodyCenter" class="reContentCell" style="height:100%;">
    <label for="ctl00_cRight_ucSMS_redSMSBodyContentHiddenTextarea" style="display:none;">
RadEditor hidden textarea
</label>
    <textarea id="ctl00_cRight_ucSMS_redSMSBodyContentHiddenTextarea" name="ctl00$cRight$ucSMS$redSMSBody" rows="4" cols="20" style="display:none;">
    </textarea>
    <iframe frameborder="0" src="javascript:'<html></html>';id="ctl00_cRight_ucSMS_redSMSBody_contentIframe" title="Rich text editor with ID ctl00_cRight_ucSMS_redSMSBody" style="width: 100%; height: 218.009px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    </iframe></td>
```

I have entered the below code to enter the data.

```
IWebElement userid = FamosDriver.WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_cRight_ucSMS_redSMSBodyCenter"));
                userid.SendKeys("Test");
```

Also I have tried the following Java script executor code.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor jst = FamosDriver.WebDriver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
         jst.executeScript("document.getElementById('ctl00_cRight_ucSMS_redSMSBodyCenter').value='testuser'");
```

Am I missing something? I dont know how to fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<textarea id="ctl00_cRight_ucSMS_redSMSBodyContentHiddenTextarea" name="ctl00$cRight$ucSMS$redSMSBody" rows="4" cols="20" style="display:none;">
    </textarea>
```

If you look into style attribute it is having `style="display:none;` display as none.

You need to change the attribute of the `textarea` and then use `send_keys()`
Use java script executor to set the attribute.

```
IWebElement userid = FamosDriver.WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_cRight_ucSMS_redSMSBodyCenter"));
IJavaScriptExecutor js =FamosDriver.WebDriver as IJavaScriptExecutor;;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].style='display: block;'", userid);
userid.SendKeys("Test");
```

Comment: It works. But it creates some other problem. I posted separate question for that. If you know answer for that, pls help on that question too. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66885762/not-able-to-retrieve-data-while-pass-arguments-using-java-script-executor

Comment: I think there was one typo. I have changed that `element` to `userid` . Hope that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are in frame as I can see this from your HTML code. That means that you just need to switch to the ifreame do some action and switch back to default content. There are multiple ways to implement it.For C# it will look like:

```
//Use one of these 4 options
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frame-id);
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("frame-name");
 
/* weblocator can be XPath, CssSelector, Id, Name, etc. */
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.weblocator("web-locator-property")));
//////YOUR ACTION
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

See more on https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/handling-frames-and-iframes-selenium-c-sharp/